# Register permenant receiver from Java code in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have searched on net and found that BroadcastReceiver registered from manifest file are permanent i.e. even if application is not running, receiver will be called.

Is there any way to get same from java code. i.e I want to write code a way that my receiver should be called even if application is not running. I want to register and unregister on specific setting done on application.

I can register it on manifest and write some preference flag and check it on receiver to execute or not. But registering from code will be more helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the receiver on the manifest but you can enable it from the code according to some setting. Look here to see [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html) how.